# if page is default then include if not default then

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic, ssi

I've read similar questions, but none seems working for me.

I have an asp site, i think classic (don't even know difference between classic and net), with few pages all with asp extension, and some html includes, one of these being a slider which I want to only display when in homepage (default.asp), and if not default then add a div to the markup.

I know the following is wrong, but just to better explain my need.

```
<%
if page == default.asp
include file="slider.html"
if page != default.asp
<div class="spacer-top"></div>
%>
```

Comment: If your files end in .asp, then you're dealing with asp-classic. ASP.net files end in .aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Like many of your predecessors in ASP-classic-land, what you're wanting is conditional includes, and the problem you're bumping into is that classic ASP doesn't do conditional includes. (The reason why is that the `#include` directive is handled long before any script on the page is parsed.)

There are various workarounds involving `Execute` or other dangerous-in-the-wrong-hands commands; search for "[asp conditional include](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134119/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/022504-1.shtml)" and you'll find more than you were bargaining for. However, in your case, it might be simpler to encase the slider display in a subroutine that you can call or not.

Slider.html:

```vbs
<%
Sub DisplaySlider()
    'code to display the slider (probably JavaScript, I'm guessing?)
    %>
    <script ...>
    </script>
    <%
End Sub
%>
```

Other pages:

```vbs
<!-- #include virtual="/slider.html" -->
<%
scriptname = Request.ServerVariables("Script_Name")
If InStr(scriptname, "default.asp") > 0 Then
    DisplaySlider
Else
    Response.Write "<div class='spacer-top'></div>"
End If
%>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've learned some new stuff ... I mean about the asp-classic, not the link you kindly gave, I read it, and did understand some of it, I am not coder, nor asp user. Anyhow I tried your suggestion, but perjaps due to not being good at it, I am not getting the slider, the spacer div works fine. I tried putting slider code where you say 'code to display ...', saved it both as html, and asp, and get error, tried putting the slider code where you put <script>, and none seems to be working. FYI the slider code is just the html of bootstrap carousel, so no script, or else.

Comment: This is the error I get when putting the html slider code in 'code to display the slider ...' - Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0400'
Expected statement
/afz_includes/jumbotron.asp, line 4
<div class="container">

Comment: @keneso: The site that Martha posted (4Guys) is a very good site for learning Classic ASP, well worth a book mark in your browser.

Comment: @keneso: that's probably worth another question. Make sure to post the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you. @Martha I'll open new question, please watch for it. ;)

Comment: Thank you. @Paul Like said I did read it, but understanding and learning it takes a bit more ;)

Comment: New question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633558/asp-conditional-include-error-microsoft-vbscript-compilation-error-800a0400

Answer (score 1):

Martha is bang on the nail.

To augment her answer I feel I should point out that system design comes into play, here. Try keeping your modules small and succinct, targeting their functionality to a particular aspect of your application's requirements. For example:

- one to deal with your data layer
- one to deal with more advanced form handling
- one to deal with *blah*

You get the idea.

Another idea is to include common functions in your `global.asa` so they're available to all modules within your application instantly.

Comment: Thank you for the input, this is an old site done by someone else that I am trying to restyle it, and while at it, thought to clean it a bit, but I am not coder, and much less asp user.