# asp conditional include error Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0400'

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ssi

I followed Martha's suggestion here:
[if page is default then include if not default then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610851/if-page-is-default-then-include-if-not-default-then)
And I am missing something, as I can't get it to display the slider.

Here is the slider code, and how I am using Martha'e suggestion.

This is the slider (bootstrap carousel) code (to be integrated with Martha's suggestion)

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row fz-slider-wrap">
            <div class="col-md-4 fz-slider-caption">
                DFD Fioriere
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 fz-slider-image">
                <div id="fz-gallery-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#fz-gallery-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#fz-gallery-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#fz-gallery-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>

                    </ol>
                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                        <img class="fz-img-box" src="images/slider/03.jpg" alt="slider 1" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                        <img class="fz-img-box" src="images/slider/01.jpg" alt="slider 2" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                        <img class="fz-img-box" src="images//slider/06.jpg" alt="slider 3" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- .jumbotron -->
```

This is what happens:
If I put the above code inside

```
<%
Sub DisplaySlider()
slider code
    %>
<%
End Sub
%>
```

I get this error when loading default.asp

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0400'
>
> Expected statement
>
> /afz_includes/jumbotron.asp, line 3

If I wrap slider code in ' I get same error but line 4
If I wrap slider code in " I get same error (line 3)
I also tried to wrap each line of slider code with ", and chnaged the " of classes and ids to ', but keep getting th error.

Here is what I put on the default.asp, and the other pages

```
<!-- #include virtual="/afz_includes/slider.html" -->
<%
scriptname = Request.ServerVariables("Script_Name")
If InStr(scriptname, "default.asp") > 0 Then
    DisplaySlider
Else
    Response.Write "<div class='fz-v-spacer-top'></div>"
End If
%>
```

I am not sure if it was a typo, anyhow I tried to save the slider both as html, and asp, but same error.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `DisplaySlider` code? Is it properly finished with a `End` keyword?

Comment: Looks like your sub procedure is missing `End Sub`.

Comment: Thank you both. Yes the end snip is there (    <%
End Sub
%>)  I just concentrated where slider code is supposed to be according to my understanding of Martha's suggestion. Updated the OP

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've put the slider's code inside the ASP code delimiters (the `<%` and `%>`), so the compiler is trying to treat it as VBScript, which it obviously isn't.

In ASP classic, you put your server-side VBScript code inside `<% %>` blocks. HTML code does *not* go inside those blocks, unless you're `Response.Write`-ing it.

```
<%
Sub DisplaySlider()
%>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        ...
    </div>
</div><!-- .jumbotron -->
<%
End Sub
%>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I thought that is not the way to go, but I tried it after using it the way you are suggesting, in this case the slider does not display, but the spacer div works fine.